# enable disable jquery tab using class or id

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to enable disable jquery tabs using class/id rather than direct index number, the tabs are being generated dynamically so i cant hard code the index number.

I have tried using this and it works fine `$("#tabs").tabs( "option", "disabled",[2])` but like i said i cant hardcode so i tried using class `$("#tabs").tabs( "option", "disabled", [$("classname").index()] )` but this is not working.

What am i missing? I have looked into jquery tabs [document](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-enable) and did not find any info on how to use class. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what worked for me

```
$("#tabs").tabs( "option", "disabled", [$("#classname").index()])
```